# Multiple paragraphs, only one read more button to show all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This piece of code loops through all paragraphs and adds a see more button at their end. I want it to show just the first few words of the first paragraph and, if you click on "see more", to show all paragraphs. I tried removing the each loop, tried to wrap it into a div and get it with .html() and then cut it but with no avail. I would appreciate an idea to point me in the right direction.

Update: maybe I wasn't clear enough: just one see more button at the end of first ten characters of the first paragraph. If you click on that it shows the full content of all paragraphs.

Please, no plugins.

```js
jQuery(function(){

    var minimized_elements = $('p');
    
    minimized_elements.each(function(){    
        var t = $(this).text();        
        if(t.length < 100) return;
        
        $(this).html(
            t.slice(0,100)+'<span>... </span><a href="#" class="more">More</a>'+
            '<span style="display:none;">'+ t.slice(100,t.length)+' <a href="#" class="less">Less</a></span>'
        );
        
    }); 
    
    $('a.more', minimized_elements).click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide().prev().hide();
        $(this).next().show();        
    });
    
    $('a.less', minimized_elements).click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().hide().prev().show().prev().show();    
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text.</p>

<p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text.</p>

<p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text.</p>
```

Comment: What is the problem?? Its unclear to me. You don't want to use `each()`??

Comment: You haven't explained what the problem is. Does your code not work?

Comment: @Manwal it loops through every paragraph. I just want a simple one that shows first few words of the first paragraph and then on click it shows all paragraphs. I just want an idea on how to do it. I tried removing the each loop and tried to get it with .html() and then cut it but it doesn't work.

Comment: wrap the part of the text that you want hidden in a `<span style="display: none">yada yada yada</span><button>Read More</button>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made some changes in your code. May be this is what you want:

```js
jQuery(function(){

    var minimized_elements = $('p');
    var counter = 1;
    minimized_elements.each(function(){    
     if(counter==1){
         $(this).addClass("first");
        var t = $(this).text();        
            if(t.length < 100) return;
            
            $(this).html(
                t.slice(0,100)+'<span>... </span><a href="#" class="more">Show</a>'+
                '<span style="display:none;">'+ t.slice(100,t.length)+' <a href="#" class="less">Hide</a></span>'
            );
     } else{
         $(this).hide();
     }
        counter++;
    }); 
    
    $('a.more', minimized_elements).click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide().prev().hide();
        $(this).next().show();
        $('p').show();        
    });
    
    $('a.less', minimized_elements).click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().hide().prev().show().prev().show();  
        $('p').not('.first').hide();
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text.</p>

<p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text.</p>

<p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is precisely what I wanted. I will put the hide button at the end of the last paragraph. Cheers!

Comment: This is the proper way to do this. Thanks for the solution. The only thing I had to change was moving the "Less" link to the end of the paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

Your code run, but i tried to figure out your problem so, I edit yours to

```
jQuery(function(){

    var minimized_elements = $('p');


    minimized_elements.each(function(){    
        var sefl = this;
        var t = $(this).text();        
        if(t.length < 100) return;

        $(this).html(
            t.slice(0,100)+'<span>... </span><a href="#" class="more">More</a>'+
            '<span class="hidden" style="display:none;">'+ t.slice(100,t.length)+' <a href="#" class="less">Less</a></span>'
        );

        $(this).find('a').click(function() {
            if ( $(this).is('.more') ) {
                $(sefl).find('.hidden').show();
                $(sefl).find('.more').hide();
            } else if ( $(this).is('.less') ) {
                $(sefl).find('.hidden').hide();
                $(sefl).find('.more').show();
            }
        });

    }); 


});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hudLaqo0/)

Comment: I have never spent so much time on a small bug. This one saved me!

Comment: Glad to hear that